# PyQt5 eventFilter not running

Tags: events, pyqt5, qtwebengine, eventfilter

I'm trying to make the url in my program automatically update as you click links in the browser and whatnot. The problem is that the eventFilter doesn't seem to run.

[Code can be found here](https://github.com/voxelvortex/YoutubeDownloader)

Comment: please add your code here.

Comment: If you click on "Code can be found here" it will bring you to the code.